# ¿Por qué no aparecen las imagenes en el carrusel?

Tags: php, yii2, carrusel, index

Este es el código que uso pero no me muestra las imagenes, estoy trabajando con yii2 basic pero no me muestra las imagenes la ruta según yo esta bien.
En el crud se agregan las imagenes y se almacenan en la carpeta de carrusel-img que esta dentro de la carpeta web pero no me salen las imagenes.

```
       <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>
        
        <?php
            
            foreach ($carrusel as $key => $value) {
        
            echo'<div class="swiper-slide">',
            '<a> <img src="/web/carrusel-img"> </a>',
            '</div>';
            '<div class="swiper-button-next"></div>';
            '<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>';
             '</div>';
            }
        ?>
```

Igual tengo este otro carrusel pero pasa lo mismo si muestra el texto pero no muestra las imagenes.

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide mb-4" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner text-center">
            <?php foreach ($carrusel as $key => $value): ?>

                <?php if ($key == 0): ?>
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                <?php endif; ?>

                        <?=
                        Html::img(
                                '@web/carrusel-img/' . $value['imagen'],
                                [
                                    'height' => '400',
                                    'width' => '1200',
                                ]
                        );
                        ?>

                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                            <p><?= $value['imagen']; ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Ya lo intente pero sigue sin aparecer las imagenes

Comment: Ya agregué otro código que estaba usando para el carrusel pero pasa lo mismo no muestra la imagen

Comment: ¿En qué parte, no entiendo?

Comment: Este es el resultado que sale:
C:\wamp64\www\basic\views\site\index.php:28:
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'imagen' => string 'uploads1/1641682466_1641525230_solgrafic.jpg' (length=44)

Comment: Este es la dirección: C:\wamp64\www\basic\views\site\web\carrusel-img/1641767999_1641682466_1641525230_solgrafic.jpg

Comment: La carpeta uploads1 la cambie por carrusel-img y ya borre las que estaban guardadas ahí y cree unas nuevas imagenes con la nueva ruta pero sigue sin aparecer las imagenes en el carrusel pero si aparece los nombres cada vez que se agrega una nueva imagen
La ruta es: C:\wamp64\www\basic\views\site\web\carrusel-img

Comment: Tengo un crud creado donde se elimina, agrega y edita, y tengo una consulta en el ActionIndex que es la siguiente consulta:        
$query = new Query();
$carrusel = $query->select("imagen")->from("carousel")->all();
return $this->render('index',['carrusel' => $carrusel]);
Y de esto es la variable $carrusel que uso en el index

Comment: Y como veo la direccion donde se guarda la imagen?

Comment: Ya lo cheque en el crud aparece la ruta y esta bien si lo guarda en el carrusel-img

Comment: Vale, borrados, te recomiendo hagas lo mismo o nadie querra ayudarte con tanto texto extra :-)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que incluir todo el html como si de una sola cadena de texto se tratara, con unas comillas rectas al inicio y al final: esto es para que se puedan incluir en su interior comillas dobles...

```
echo'<div class="swiper-slide">
     <a> <img src="/web/carrusel-img"> </a>
     </div>
     <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
     <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
     </div>';
```

Comment: Ya lo puse como lo corregiste pero siguen sin aparecer las imagenes

Answer (score 0):

Así quedaría la solución de la ruta que no encontraba.

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide mb-4" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner text-center">
                <?php foreach ($carrusel as $key => $img): ?>
    
                    <?php if ($key == 0): ?>
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                    <?php endif; ?>
    
                            <?= Html::img("@web/{$img['imagen']}") ?>
    
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                <p><?= $img['imagen']; ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
```

Comment: Me alegro que lo hayas visto al fin :-)

Comment: Sii, me ayudarón en otro grupo y esa fue la solución de la ruta para que se vean las imagenes

Comment: Bueno, si te fijas un poco verás que han hecho lo que te comentaba, es decir, han visto que duplicabas la ruta `carrusel-img` tanto en el código como en la tabla dando como resultado una ruta incorrecta. Yo te pedia arreglarlo en la base de datos porque de este modo puedes variar el nombre de carpeta cuando quieras sin volver a cambiar la ruta en la tabla. Esta otra solución la han hecho directamente sobre el código quitando tan solo `carrusel-img` de la ruta y dejando la tabla tal como esta y quizas en un futuro debas cambiar los registros de nuevo uno a uno por cambio de carpeta.